# how to migrate flutter mid-level existing project null safety?

Tags: flutter, dart, null-safety

I am trying to upgrade my existing Flutter project to null-safety.
When I upgrade the Flutter version to the latest one, as expected it gives thousands of errors due to null safety.

What is the best approach to resolve this issue? Please consider that it is a mid-level existing project.

Comment: Have you tried following the [migration guide](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)?

Comment: Yes I did, 
As I see, The commands like dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety , and dart migrate don't exist anymore.

Comment: You need to down grade your dart version

Comment: The page I share clearly states: **Dart 2.19 is the final release that supports null-safety migration**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But sorry I am really confused. Is it a really good approach to downgrade the project? Is there any other better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there is no easy way to do it without having to seeing error.
I was able to update two projects with `dart migrate` and then view the migration suggestions by visiting the link in command line.

If haven't, follow the instruction here and watch the video to understand the process.

https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide#step2-migrate

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
When was the last time you updated the projects using dart migrate?
As I can see now commands like dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety , and dart migrate don't exist anymore.

Comment: About  8 months ago. 

Dart migrate, takes care of most of the things it self, it will ask you about things it's not too sure about. 

Right, seems like dart migrate was removed in dart 3. Try the suggestion in the link below to help with your migration . 
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/50319\

https://dart.dev/resources/dart-3-migration